# imp.find_module()

Tags: python, imp

According to the [`imp.load_module`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.load_module) documentation, "The caller is responsible for closing the *file* argument." If I pass the file object returned from `imp.find_module` to `imp.load_module`, am I still responsible for closing the file object? Or will `imp.load_module` close it for me?